# Using JavaScript to change Less files

Tags: javascript, css, less

I want to change a property of a Less file with JavaScript.
This is my code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content-main--inner').style.border = '1px solid yellow!important';
```

I've tried it with `!important` and without it.

But that doesn't work, the property doesn't change.
I think the problem is here:

```
('content-main--inner')
```

Is it possible to manipulate Less files with JavaScript?

Comment: Isn't it a little late to modify Less code once the element is available in the DOM ?

Comment: The real issue seems to be that `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, not a single element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList, not a single element, you'd have to iterate

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('content-main--inner');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    elems[i].style.border = '1px solid yellow';
}
```

Note that `!important` can't be set in javascript or inline styles

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your less file with js wouldn't do you any good because at the time you would modify the file it would have already been translated to css

As someone commented, `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList meaning you need to do the following to modify the first element

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content-main--inner')[0].style.border = '1px solid yellow !important';
```

or if you want to modify all elements with the class `content-main--inner`

```
var elements =  document.getElementsByClassName('content-main--inner')

for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].style.border = '1px solid yellow !important';
}
```